# Typing An Api Calling Function With Generics

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

I'm trying to make a function that can call multiple APIs and gives strong typing for each argument: `api` - the name of the api, `route` - the desired route within 'api', and `params` - a JSON of the parameters required by the api and route chosen.

I've created an example of what I'd like to in a [TS Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggCgSQHIEMC2EDOUC8UBEA5gPbGEA2E+UAPgSCgBan4DcAsAFBeiRQBKxAK7AsAHhhQIAD1EA7ACbZ4ydFgB8uKAG8uUfVBJlKALgIRFYYgEs5wAIzU6+Cwqu3gAJjZ6DDZsRmLpY2dgDMPpwAvgDaMAC6HNycvNCCIhBwKABO6JgSUrKuyoioGJgANAKF8koCwqL5MOqaeLqcBoakFBBm7Z2dru529n2+AwNyamaYwNm2hEkT+lFLy0OhXmMdy53EwIwQ2WW9ULPzcovjA6vXtzv6-qTbuxseYS+7BvuH2QDyByOJxmcwWawm90691iCRi-ESXC4AGNiHJZoUIEiMloCjJaiVVOUqvwasV6hkmi0ABQoMDWMwwKrZBqnfhVMA5PJmdKiLK5NBNYnqACUuE0-QMAHpJVAAHTyqAohQQLhRRGcGSYjJUgDkRh6OqqOreI0NOl8UwwZh1AHEIMRsoRoAB1FCYRgLYConX6VXCpJAA).

Here's the code:

```js
type APINames = "google" | "yahoo";

type Routes<A extends APINames> = {
    google: "endpoint1" | "endpoint2";
    yahoo: "endpoint3";
}[A];

type RouteParams<A extends APINames, R extends Routes<A>> = {
    google: {
        endpoint1: {
            name: string;
        };
        endpoint2: {
            otherName: string;
        };
    };
    yahoo: {
        endpoint3: {
            otherOtherName: string;
        };
    };
}[A][R];

const execute = <A extends APINames, R extends Routes<A>>(api: A, route: R, params: RouteParams<A, R>) => {
    // ... code
}

execute('google', 'endpoint1', {
  name: 'George Washington'  
});
```

I appear to be getting a type error on my `RouteParams` type because while `[A]` is a legal first index, `[R]` isn't a legal second index because `R` is now the type `'endpoint1' | 'endpoint2' | 'endpoint3'` and some subset of those don't exist on each key within the `RouteParams` object. The code above actually gives the desired typing help when using the `execute` function; I just need to resolve the TS error on `RouteParams`. I suspect there's a utility type that would solve this and I'm also open to solutions that are a completely different structure.

**The ultimate goal is to have a function that takes 3 arguments, the first is an api name from a union type, the second is a route from a union type associated with the api name, and the third is a json parameters object associated with the api name and route combination.**

Comment: You're looking for something like [this version](https://tsplay.dev/w2kMbN) then?  If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yes! that is excellent - thank you. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

The approach I'd take is to extract the object type you've mentioned in `RouteParams` into its own interface:

```
interface ApiMap {
    google: {
        endpoint1: {
            name: string;
        };
        endpoint2: {
            otherName: string;
        };
    };
    yahoo: {
        endpoint3: {
            otherOtherName: string;
        };
    };
}
```

And then describe the operation explicitly in terms of [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) and [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html):

```
const execute = <A extends keyof ApiMap, R extends keyof ApiMap[A]>(
    api: A, route: R, params: ApiMap[A][R] // no error
) => {    // ... code
}
```

That compiles with no error and it still behaves as desired from the caller's side:

```
execute('google', 'endpoint1', { name: 'George Washington' });
execute('google', 'endpoint2', { otherName: 'Abraham Lincoln' });
execute('yahoo', 'endpoint3', { otherOtherName: 'one of them Roosevelts or something' });
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIAdgFk7uQbwFgAoZM5AcwHsqKAbCALgJPLeQhABN0rQwAjMyKl2YkHAC2TZAGcwUUBQDcrMcgC+q0WM48+4AEzC168lTAALaADkpM+YpArT7La-c7kATziWaJl5serz8AMyBZmwW1lAA8la29syOStpmnmyeGiQkCFQg8hwAHhAIAK6QyAC8yAA8qCWQ3LLIANYQ3lQwaJg46AA0yABKTXqtHV09GNi4ANqoALoAfAAUrrjAzKhDUFSVMsND6HBQUrLbffNLc8OLJACUNcsEbAD0b8gAdD-I+VwQEg5YgkCClCqQVYAcmotAYUKGUJCBkECNeEmkzChAHEIFQoBQUAB1OCySxKMAFKGaB7aMFlA7Q2H0CBopHcUJGNH4ZAxJKY5BQ1AAIzOlikyAAMqB8nQQNSNLTQeDGVDfP4qGzkeFubzEvF9XYBVCCihushEpIRjRZBAAG4QOhgVr4uRUaRWJQKpUg31AA)